# Google Play Console- uploaded a new version on Internal test but production version also goes on review

Tags: android, google-play-internal-testing

I uploaded and published an app for internal testing, yet the play store console shows it in review. But after submissions on internal test previous rejected version of production also shows in review. please see the image [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F68KF.png)

I don't want production version to go in review. is there any way to stop this.

my app already got rejected twice and I don't want to take any risk to reject my app again and again, that why I am putting my app on internal test as suggested by Google support team.

Can anyone help me with this please.

Comment: Did you get any help with this? The same thing has just happened to me with a rejected build after I uploaded a new version to Internal Test to make sure the issue was resolved.

Comment: Same is happening with me. how to resolve it